# Is there a JPanel equivalent for MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, user-controls

Im my application I want to implement the feature of when a user click on a button show a Panel which will consist of some user controls. I know In Java I can easily use `Jpanel` and use `setVisible()` method to get this done easily. But this is an MFC application. I couldn't find any built or customized component that I can use for my purpose.

I also tried `GroupBox`. But it is not grouping the components logically.
What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting a `CDialog` derived class. Create the dialog and its controls in the `Resource Editor` and then create the associated class via the `Class Wizard`. ps. As I understand it the VS-Express editions do not support MFC.

Answer (score 2):

As user1793036 says, start by creating a dialog resource and `CDialog` derived class for the panel. In the dialog resource properties turn off the Title Bar style. In the code call `Create` for the dialog and then `SetWindowPos` to place it where you want it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

MFC is nothing but a thin wrapper over Win32 API for windows and controls. The core Win32 API doesn't provide any feature to group controls in a group-box or panel. One way is to have a window and make that window parent of all required controls. Unfortunately, this isn't easy to do.

I suggest you, since you are learning, to drop the idea. Instead, learn what you can achieve with existing set of features provided by MFC/Win32. With MFC/Win32, you would, mostly need to derive/subclass a class/window to get something fancy (such as colored list-control).